# getting: *** Assertion failure in -[UIStoryboardPushSegue perform]

Tags: ios, storyboard, segue, assertion

I am Using Storyboard for a master/detail iPad app.
MenutabViewController is a UITabBarViewController.
Another Scene of the app starting from the same Controller, doing similar PUSH segues (push->master, push-detail) is OK. But this one gives me this message.
This message is never given again to someone else because I Googled a lot :p .

You can see an image of the storyboard here (not allowed to post one)
http://qupload.com/images/stackoverq.png

```
2012-11-13 17:13:47.244[9777:13d03] prepareForSegue: settingsStoreSegue
2012-11-13 17:13:47.244[9777:13d03] *** Assertion failure in -[UIStoryboardPushSegue perform], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2372/UIStoryboardBuiltInSegues.m:24
2012-11-13 17:13:52.323 IpposFfs[9777:13d03] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', **reason: 'Expected a navigation controller, but got an instance of 'MenuTabViewController' instead, while performing a split view controller push segue (identifier 'settingsStoreSegue') for index #0'**
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1cd6012 0x1606e7e 0x1cd5e78 0x109cf35 0x9a3ca2 0x995ad9 0x630422 0x7326b 0x5fd8d5 0x5fdb3d 0x1004e83 0x1c95376 0x1c94e06 0x1c7ca82 0x1c7bf44 0x1c7be1b 0x1c307e3 0x1c30668 0x54e65c 0x2cbd 0x2be5)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

Comment: The message seems clear: if you're going to **push** a new controller, it needs to be done through a navigation controller rather than a tab bar controller.

Comment: Can you please see the image I uploaded because I am really sure that the rootViewController that is supposed to be the problem works OK with the other scene, where i also push View Controllers with Push Segues

Comment: It's hard to follow all the lines in the picture but the error is claiming that the start point of the segue is not a navigation controller.  What may also be confusing things is the way you use the tab bar controller...the docs say: *"When deploying a tab bar interface, you must install this view as the root of your window. Unlike other view controllers, a tab bar interface should never be installed as a child of another view controller."*.

Comment: Really Sorry For the previus Lame ScreenShot.
And thank u for pointing me this docs saying... It's good knowledge

BUT:
I edited the post with a far more clearer screenshop.
As u can now see, the rootViewController is not the MenuTabController, but each NavigationControllers who start each scene. They are similar, the one scene works the other doesn't...

Please help! !!!

Comment: There's not much I can tell you.  If you're trying to use a tab bar controller as a sub-controller, there's obviously no guarantee that it will work.  If your code enters `prepareForSegue:`, maybe logging the value of `sender` would tell you something but the main point is still that you're going against a very strong statement: *"should never..."*